# Upgrade PHP to 5.4.14 on OS X 10.7.5 Lion

Tags: apache-http-server, php, osx-lion

I am trying to upgrade PHP on my Mac. I have downloaded PHP 5.4.14 and have no problems with the configuration command:

```
./configure \
 --prefix=/usr \
 --mandir=/usr/share/man \
 --infodir=/usr/share/info \
 --sysconfdir=/private/etc \
 --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs \
 --enable-cli \
 --with-config-file-path=/etc \
 --with-libxml-dir=/usr \
 --with-openssl=/usr \
 --with-kerberos=/usr \
 --with-zlib=/usr \
 --enable-bcmath \
 --with-bz2=/usr \
 --enable-calendar \
 --with-curl=/usr \
 --enable-dba \
 --enable-exif \
 --enable-ftp \
 --with-gd \
 --with-freetype-dir=/usr/X11 \
 --with-jpeg-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-66.6~1/Root/usr/local \
 --with-png-dir=/usr/X11 \
 --enable-gd-native-ttf \
 --with-icu-dir=/usr \
 --with-iodbc=/usr \
 --with-ldap=/usr \
 --with-ldap-sasl=/usr \
 --with-libedit=/usr \
 --enable-mbstring \
 --enable-mbregex \
 --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
 --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
 --without-pear \
 --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
 --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock \
 --with-readline=/usr \
 --enable-shmop \
 --with-snmp=/usr \
 --enable-soap \
 --enable-sockets \
 --enable-sysvmsg \
 --enable-sysvsem \
 --enable-sysvshm \
 --with-tidy \
 --enable-wddx \
 --with-xmlrpc \
 --without-iconv \
 --with-xsl=/usr \
 --enable-zip \
 --with-pcre-regex=/usr \
 --with-pgsql=/usr \
 --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr
```

When I do a `make test` I get a long slew of stuff with the following at the end:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_php_pcre_compile", referenced from:
      _pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache in php_pcre.o
  "_php_pcre_exec", referenced from:
      _php_pcre_grep_impl in php_pcre.o
      _php_pcre_replace_impl in php_pcre.o
      _php_pcre_match_impl in php_pcre.o
      _php_pcre_split_impl in php_pcre.o
      _check_fmt in softmagic.o
      _php_filter_validate_email in logical_filters.o
      _php_filter_validate_regexp in logical_filters.o
      ...
  "_php_pcre_free", referenced from:
      _php_pcre_match_impl in php_pcre.o
  "_php_pcre_fullinfo", referenced from:
      _pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache in php_pcre.o
      _php_pcre_grep_impl in php_pcre.o
      _make_subpats_table in php_pcre.o
      _php_pcre_replace_impl in php_pcre.o
      _php_pcre_match_impl in php_pcre.o
      _php_pcre_split_impl in php_pcre.o
  "_php_pcre_get_substring_list", referenced from:
      _php_pcre_match_impl in php_pcre.o
  "_php_pcre_maketables", referenced from:
      _pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache in php_pcre.o
  "_php_pcre_study", referenced from:
      _pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache in php_pcre.o
  "_php_pcre_version", referenced from:
      _zm_info_pcre in php_pcre.o
      _zm_startup_pcre in php_pcre.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1
```

I have updated PCRE on the system to version 8.32, and I require it due to some zlib dependencies amongst other things and general perl regular expression stuff. I'm at a loss as to why my `make test` won't pass.

Any help would be appreciated to fix this problem.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with PCRE as a shared library? `--with-pcre-regex=shared,/usr`. You may need to `make clean` first.

Comment: No I have not tried that, but I will! As a side note, can you briefly explain, or point me to a specific resource that discusses why this might be the case?

Comment: I just did the make clean and then modified the configure command, the output said this: `checking for PCRE headers location... configure: error: Could not find pcre.h in shared,/usr`

Comment: I've found some libraries are already on OS X but w/o the header files. The `shared,/path` option allows extensions to use the systems pre-installed library. For PCRE, the `--with-prec-refex` [my not be needed](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php) as PCRE is included with php-5.3+. Where is PCRE-8.32 installed? You can locate it by executing `pcre-config --prefix` and use the return path as the `--with-prec-refex` argument.

Comment: I am altogether not going to try and include the configure command `--with-pcre-regex` and see if that works.

Comment: `make test` performed without a PCRE error and compiled after I removed the pcre command. PCRE is running at the latest version. Sorry for the issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Simply remove the `--with-pcre-regex` options. Modern version of PHP ship with PCRE library (located in ext/pcre/pcrelib), and is considered part of the core PHP build.

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php),

> **Note:**
>
> As of PHP 5.3.0 this extension cannot be disabled and is therefore
>   always present.
>
> It is still possible to build against an external PCRE library by
>   using --with-pcre-regex=DIR

**Option 2**

As the note above states, you can build PHP with an external PCRE library. To do so, updated the `--with-pcre-regex` option with value returned by `pcre-config --prefix`.

Comment: Typo:  "To do so, **update** the --w**i**th-pcre-regex option with value returned by pcre-config --prefix."

Comment: Actually, the typo is still there.  :^/